# Getting coordinates from Romanian zipcode in google maps

Tags: google-maps, zipcode

When I try to use google maps API to get coordinates via a romanian zipcode I don't get coordinates back that are situated in Romania. My search request is for example "040679 Romania" or "040679 RO". How can I make my search explicitly for the romanian country?

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=040679+RO&sensor=false
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=040679+Romania&sensor=false
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=040679+Romanian&sensor=false
```

The links above all give incorrect coordinates back. Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

Try using [ComponentFiltering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ComponentFiltering) for country, for example:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&components=country:RO|postal_code=040679&sensor=false

Comment: Thank you for you reaction. This has helpt me a little, but when i use different a different zipcode than the example I still get the same coordinates back within. And would like to get the coordinates of the zipcode I inserted so that I can calculate the distance between other coordinates.

Comment: Can you give the example zip codes you are comparing? Also, check out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/ - google can calculate the distance for you

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I use the zipcode 330128 or 407035 i get the same coördinats back in JSON. I already have the code for calculate the distance.

Comment: I fixed the URL, it needs to have pipeline as delimiter, but now it gets no results, I don't know why

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, my colleague says that the problem might be with the data that google has on the country, could this be the problem?